# Using xpath to cllick with selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to click "Claim reward" by selenium python and it doesn't work:

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6MLc.png)

Here is my code:

`WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, ('//button[@class="chakra-button css-g0vki9"]'))).click()`

Can someone help me? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like below

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Claim Reward')]"))).click()
```

***OR***

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="chakra-button css-g0vki9"]'))).click()
```

***OR By CSS SELECTOR***

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.chakra-button.css-g0vki9'))).click()
```

***IMPORT***

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Please accept the answer, if this helps you to help others.